# Loading second component causes "The template specified for component SidebarComponent is not a string"

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have just started learning angular and i tried to create a simple dashboard.

I've created 2 componentents, DashboardComponent and SidebarComponent.

Dashboard loads fine, but when i load SidebarComponent i'm getting a error on browser "The template specified for component SidebarComponent is not a string"[image]

SidebarComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar-component',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.ts',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent {}
```

App.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Both of them are also loaded in app.component

```
<sidebar-component></sidebar-component>
<dashboard></dashboard>
```

Comment: The error speaks for itself... you're referring to a `.ts` file instead of `.html`... `templateUrl: './sidebar.component.ts',`

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you very much, please post this as a answer so i can accept it

Comment: but even if I add `html` instead of `ts`, my `component.ts` for the second file does not bind data / been called.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error speaks for itself...

You're referring to a `.ts` file instead of `.html`.

Change this line:

```
templateUrl: './sidebar.component.ts'
```

to:

```
templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html'
```